# vim - binary increment with one click

Tags: vim

Any help appreciated:

CTRL-A increments a number but it only does so in a decimal fashion.

I'd like to increment binary style with one click:

**source:**

```
3'b000: clk_out = clk_in0;
3'b000: clk_out = clk_in0;
3'b000: clk_out = clk_in0;
3'b000: clk_out = clk_in0;
3'b000: clk_out = clk_in0;
3'b000: clk_out = clk_in0;
```

**dest:**

```
3'b000: clk_out = clk_in0;
3'b001: clk_out = clk_in1;
3'b010: clk_out = clk_in2;
3'b011: clk_out = clk_in3;
3'b100: clk_out = clk_in4;
3'b001: clk_out = clk_in5;
```

Any tips appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you have to implement it by your own. or use some external tool.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently completed a plugin, [***magnum.vim***](https://github.com/glts/vim-magnum), that does base conversion of integers of any size.

With this plugin the solution is a (long) one-liner.

```
nnoremap g<C-A> :<C-U>s/[01]\+/\=printf('%0'.len(submatch(0)).'s',magnum#Int(submatch(0),2).Add(magnum#Int(v:count1)).String(2))/<CR>
```

With this in your vimrc you can use `g CTRL-A` to increment binary numbers. Giving a count works too.

[image: Demo of g CTRL-A mapping]

Note that magnum.vim has a dependency on another library, Google's [*maktaba*](https://github.com/google/maktaba), so you may find this approach too heavy for your purposes.

Comment: I've always wanted to make a little screencast ... :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not built-in way; the `'nrformats'` option only supports alphabetical, octal, and hexadecimal formats.

The [SwapIt - Extensible keyword swapper](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2294) plugin overloads the `<C-a>` / `<C-x>` commands with custom sequences. As long as your binary numbers are small, you could configure all permutations there (it supports a `[count]` like the original command). That would probably need to include the `3'b` prefix, too.

Alternatively, you'd have to implement a custom function that handles binary numbers; you can probably get the implementation ideas from the mentioned plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem and here is my workaround.

The vim version I use (8.1.873) supports nrformats=bin. Below is the help from vim:

> bin:    If included, numbers starting with "0b" or "0B" will be
>         considered to be binary.  Example: Using CTRL-X on
>         "0b1000" subtracts one, resulting in "0b0111".

That is to say, you can use `set nrformats=bin` to let `<C-a>` increase binary numbers. But in this case, you need to insert a column of 0's temporarily (use `<C-v>` to select the column of b's and then press `I0<Esc>`) to make vim treat them as binary numbers.

After you are done with the binary numbers, you can delete the column of 0's (similarly, use `<C-v>` to select the column of 0's and press `d` to delete).